# Message to Survivors

Tags: language, geography, outer-space

Your spaceship pulls out of uberdrive (a new transportation mode that has overtaken hyperdrive in the space exploration market) and you find yourself gazing at the beauty of Earth for the first time in decades (though to you it has been a far shorter time). It has been a while since you and two dozen others were sent out in search of a potential new home. You dock at the I.S.S. IV and find it empty. Puzzled, you find a hologram in the control station and play it. In English, it plays:

> Hello. Humanity has been forced to relocate by an alien menace known as the Fblthp. One of our scouts found a viable area for
>   humanity to try and establish itself. If you are receiving this message, you are likely one of
>   our scouts returning from your reconnaissance. Or you may be one of the Fblthp race. Unfortunately,
>   the Fblthp understand English so we cannot simply tell you our new location, but they have practically no understanding of other languages or
>   our geography. To ensure that, if you're one of us, you return to us with your vital intel, we have hidden the clues
>   to our location in etymology so that the Fblthp cannot decipher it. Use the light language training that you received and decipher
>   the U.S. cities via their etymological origin; if you get to a name and it seems ambiguous,  choose the capital with that name.
>   Find the cities, and you will find our new home.

**CLUES**

> Holy Faith
>   Village of Jack's Progeny
>   Country of the Dove
>   Ford of Frank
>   White Oak
>   City of Red People
>   Emperor Aurelius' New City
>   Town of the Husband/Man
>   River Strait

Where is humanity holed up?

Comment: If we're expected to find numerical values and convert them to the location of a star, then [tag:astronomy] might work better than [tag:outer-space]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is:

> The new home of mankind are the **Pleiades**.
>
>  (The geographic positions of the nine cities are very similar
>  to the positions of the nine brightest stars in the Pleiades;
>  see the image at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleiades )

The nine cities are:

> 1. Holy Faith  =  Santa Fe, New Mexico
> 2. Village of Jack's Progeny  =  Jacksonville, Florida
> 3. Country of the Dove  =  Columbia, South Carolina
> 4. Ford of Frank  = Frankfort, Kentucky
> 5. White Oak  =   Albuquerque, New Mexico
> 6. City of Red People  =  Oklahoma City, Oklahoma
> 7. Emperor Aurelius' New City  =  New Orleans, Louisiana
> 8. Town of the Husband/Man  = Charleston, West Virginia
> 9. River Strait  =  Detroit, Michigan

Comment: Emperor Aurelius' founded Kaine Polis ("New City") as a new capital in Armenia. I don't' know yet how that translates to a US city.

Comment: There actually is an Aurelius, New York, named after the Emperor.

Comment: polis could point to Minneapolis as well , but Minneapolis means water city, Im not sure how the water bit would fit. Could also be indianapolis, or annapolis.

Comment: Could also be Kannapolis, North Carolina

Comment: 7 might be new orleans.

Comment: @Anachor: New Orleans seems correct. Orléans (the Old Orleans in France) was rebuilt under Aurelius, and at that time called "Aurelianum" or "Aureliana Civitas" (= city of Aurelius).

Comment: Has anyone tried pinpointing these on a map? Either simply their location or tracing lines from one to another. It might draw something, a message, an object etc...

Comment: I gave graphing them a shot, I'm thinking maybe they form a constellation?It fits the outer space theme although nothing seemed apparent at first glance. Its tough not knowing what number 3 should be, and not knowing number 8 at all.

Comment: @KBusc, you're onto it! #3 is Columbia, not Columbus. Get #9 and you should find it among common constellations (you could possibly recognize without #9)

Comment: I suck at constellations, but if anyone can give it a real shot, [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Santa+Fe+New+Mexico|+Jacksonville+Florida|+Columbia+South+Carolina|+Frankfort+Kentucky|+Albuquerque+New+Mexico|+Oklahoma+City+Oklahoma|+New+Orleans+Louisiana|+Detroit+Michigan) are the cities plotted ([hardlink](http://i.imgur.com/uQ8JYFp.jpg)).

Comment: That almost looks like a dipper, but there'd be two cities on the right side that should be on the tail on the left side.

Comment: There can't be many constellations with 9 stars...

Comment: The Town of the Husband/Man should roughly form an equilateral triangle together with Detroit and Frankfort, most likely somewhere in Pennsylvania or West Virginia (or Maryland?).

Comment: You nailed it @Gamow! The last city is not as perfectly placed as I would like. It is a capital of a state. According to etymonline.com, this town is named after king, whose name is ultimately derived from a Middle German word for husband/man. Once you figure that out, I'll happily accept your answer.

Comment: Indeed: Charles, from Medieval Latin Carolus, from Middle High German Karl, literally "man, husband".